# Why not os.path.join use os.path.sep or os.sep?

Tags: python, path

As we know, windows accept both `"\"` and `"/"` as separator.
But in python, `"\"` is used. For example, call `os.path.join("foo","bar")`, `'foo\\bar'` will be returned. What's annoying is that there's an escape character, so you cannot just copy the path string and paste to your explorer location bar.

I wonder is there any way to make python use `"/"` as default separator, I've tried change the value of os.path.sep and os.sep to `"/"`, but `os.path.join` still use `"\\"`.

what's the right way?

**PS:**

I just don't understand why python is using "\" as default separator on windows, maybe old version of windows don't support "/"?

Comment: os.path.sep should be used for joining *filenames* and *directory* names...who said that os.path.sep has to be used for URLs????

Comment: Why using `os.path.join` if you don't care about the correct path seperator in the end?

Comment: Well you could create your own function which uses '/' if on Windows or uses `os.path.join` on other platforms.  Or you could replace '\\' with '/' (or '\') in the path before you display it.

Comment: @BigYellowCactus Because my program may run on other system, but I just want to change the separator on windows.

Comment: @ThemeZ Are there systems other than windows that uses backslashes as path seperator?

Comment: @cdarke That's a resolution, but I think it may be more elegant if I can choose my own separator for specific system?

Comment: @BigYellowCactus I'm not sure, could you tell all systems that run python and their separator?

Comment: @ThemeZ I think the only other system that uses backslash is Symbian OS. Btw, I don't see a problem at all, since you can just call `print`, and the extra backslash is gone. See my answer

Comment: "\" was what Windows used originally, (even if the knew, or should knew, that "\" is escape character in Unix and will cause problems in integration later. So Python does the Right Thing (tm). Only later MSFTies decided to join rest of the world and allow for "/". So now they do have TWO standard separators. The more standards the merrier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not define a custom display function?

e.g.

```
def display_path(path):
    return path.replace("\\", "/")
```

And if you want to substitute `str.join` for `os.path.join`, you can just do this (`str.join` expects a single list, `os.path.join` expects `*args`):

```
join = lambda *args: "/".join(args)
```

Perhaps better would be to let Python normalize everything, then replace, e.g.:

```
join = lambda *args: os.path.join(*args).replace("\\", "/")
```

The only issue with the above might be on posix when there is a space in the file path.

You could then put an `if` statement at the top of your utils file and define `display_path` and `join` as a no-op and as os.path.join respectively if not on Windows.

Answer (score 13):

To answer your question as simply as possible, just use posixpath instead of os.path.

So instead of:

```
from os.path import join
join('foo', 'bar')
# will give you either 'foo/bar' or 'foo\\bar' depending on your OS
```

Use:

```
from posixpath import join
join('foo', 'bar')
# will always give you 'foo/bar'
```

Answer (score 7):

It is all about how Python detects your os:

```
# in os.py
if 'posix' in _names:
    ...
    import posixpath as path   

elif 'nt' in _names:
    ...
    import ntpath as path
```

So, on Windows the `ntpath` module is loaded. If you check the `ntpath.py` and `posixpath.py` modules you'd notice that `ntpath.join()` is a bit more complex and that is also because of the reason you've mentioned: Windows understands `/` as a path separator.

Bottomline: although you can use `posixpath.join()` in Windows (as long as the arguments are in `POSIX` format), I would not recommend doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend doing this.

Note that while windows does accept slash `/` as path separator also, it has a different meaning in some contexts.

It's treated as relative path using `cd`, for example:

**Command line:**

> c:\Users\YourUser> cd /FooBar
> c:\FooBar

Here, `/` substitutes the drive letter.

---

Also, I don't see a problem at all with copying the strings, since if you `print` the string, the string is displayed as you wish:

**Python interpreter:**

> >>> import os
> >>> print os.path.join("c:\", "foo","bar")
> c:\foo\bar
> >>>

---

Comment: "/" is also root folder on linux, so that's not a problem. And you're right, it's not a problem when printed, but it make me upset when debugging.

Comment: So when and where excatly is this a problem? Which IDE do you use?

Comment: I mean, when debugging, backslash shows as "\\" in your variable watcher right? And there're too many paths I don't want to print them all..

Comment: @ThemeZ Yeah, but which IDE are you using? Eclipse? Wing? IDLE?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but the [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12086577/1757831) is incorrect.

Windows has a concept of working directory and working drive. `/` is treated as **absolute path** on your **current working drive**, since Windows has no concept of single root. In the above example `cd /FooBar` goes to `C:\foobar` because the working drive is C:, not because C: is "root" drive or somehow special.

Here's an example:

```
C:\Users\user> cd /
C:\> d:
D:\> cd /Users
The system cannot find the path specified.
D:\> mkdir test
D:\> cd test
D:\test> cd c:/Users
D:\test> cd /
D:\> cd test
D:\test> c:
C:\Users\> d:
D:\test>
```