# Python - Can (or should) I change os.path.sep?

Tags: python

I am writing a script to parse multiple log files and maintain a list of the files that have been processed. When I read the list of files to process I use `os.walk` and get names similar to the following:

```
C:/Users/Python/Documents/Logs\ServerUI04\SystemOut_13.01.01_20.22.25.log
```

This is created by the following code:

```
filesToProcess.extend(os.path.join(root, filename) for filename in filenames if logFilePatternMatch.match(filename))
```

It appears that "root" used forward slashes as the separator (I am on Windows and find that more convenient) but "filename" uses backslashes so I end up with an inconsistent path for the file as it contains a mixture of forward and back slashes as separators.

I have tried setting the separator with:

```
os.path.sep = "/"
```

and

```
os.sep = "/"
```

Before the .join but it seems to have no effect. I realize that in theory I could manipulate the string but longer term I'd like my script to run on Unix as well as Windows so would prefer that it be dynamic if possible.

Am I missing something?

Update:

Based on the helpful responses below it looks like my problem was self inflicted, for convenience I had set the initial path used as root like this:

```
logFileFolder = ['C:/Users/Python/Documents/Logs']
```

When I changed it to this:

```
logFileFolder = ['C:\\Users\\Python\\Documents\\Logs']
```

Everything works and my resulting file paths all use the "\" throughout. It looks like my approach was wrong in that I was trying to get Python to change behavior rather than correcting what I was setting as a value.

Thank you!

Comment: I'll go out on a limb and say that setting `os.sep` is probably not the right solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why not os.path.join use os.path.sep or os.sep?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086224/why-not-os-path-join-use-os-path-sep-or-os-sep)

Comment: As an anser to that duplicate question points out, `os.path` works by importing `posixpath` or `ntpath` depending on your OS.  Interestingly, you can see in the source code of those modules that the path separator is hard-coded as a string literal inside the `join` function, so you won't be able to change it without writing your own `join` function.

Comment: where is root being set?  thats kind of critical to the answer...

Comment: @Justin.Wood: root comes from the first parameter to `os.walk`, that is `os.path.join`-ed with the dirnames in yields of recursive calls to itself.

Comment: I (think I) set root as a string to the log file folder, in it I used forward slashes, are you saying that if I used backslashes (doubled) then I'd probably be okay, that the issue is that I chose to use a forward slash? I'll try changing my log folder parameter, thank you.

Comment: See also: [How should I write a Windows path in a Python string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2953834/)

Answer (score 8):

I would keep my fingers off `os.sep` and use `os.path.normpath()` on the result of combining the root and a filename:

```
filesToProcess.extend(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(root, filename)) 
            for filename in filenames if logFilePatternMatch.match(filename))
```

Answer (score 6):

I have preferred the following utility function.

```
from os.path import sep, join

def pjoin(*args, **kwargs):
  return join(*args, **kwargs).replace(sep, '/')
```

It converts both variations (linux style and windows style) to linux style. Both windows and linux supports '/' separator in python.

I rejected the simplistic **os.sep.join(['str','str','str'])** because it does not take into account existing separators. Take the following case with sep.join vs vanilla join:

```
In[79]: os.sep.join(['/existing/my/', 'short', 'path'])
Out[79]: '/existing/my/\\short\\path'
In[80]: os.path.join('/existing/my/', 'short', 'path')
Out[80]: '/existing/my/short\\path'
```

The vanilla join could be repaired with the suggested:

```
In[75]: os.path.normpath(os.path.join('/existing/my/', 'short', 'path'))
Out[75]: '\\existing\\my\\short\\path'
```

So far so good. But then we introduce the following scenario where we will be interacting with linux from windows.

```
local_path = os.path.normpath(os.path.join('C:\\local\\base', 'subdir', 'filename.txt'))
remote_path = os.path.normpath(os.path.join('/remote/base', 'subdir', 'filename.txt'))
sftp_server.upload(local_path, remote_path)
```

The above will then fail because the sftp server expects a '/' separator while os.path.normpath will on windows normalize to '\'.

By using the pjoin utility function or similar, it will work cross OS, web, ftp, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I use `'/'.join([path1, path2])` to solve this problem, because '/' works well in windows and linux.

Comment: This wont work in all cases, though. For example, `explorer.exe` only accepts path arguments specified with `\ `.

Answer (score 1):

You are better off not touching `os.sep` and `os.path.sep` as they are not what `os.path.join` is using. You could use `os.path.normpath` as suggested by Anthon. Another alternative is to have your own simple path join:

`os.sep.join([i1,i2,i3])`