# os.path.join is giving wrong path, how to do this correctly?

Tags: python

So i'm trying to create path using the code mentioned below:

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'folder_abc','file.abc')
```

But it keeps giving the wrong path.
i.e for the above statement, value of path variable is set to :

```
C:/User/abc\folder_abc\file.abc
```

see, before abc '/' is used and after it '\' .
Why is this happening ?

Comment: What is wrong with that path?

Comment: see, before abc '/' is used and after it '\' .

Comment: You may want to [edit] that into your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is described in the Python docs see here:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join

It means, that your operating system separator is set to '\' and not as you would like to '/'. but touching these variables is not recommended as described here in another stackoverflow post:

[Python - Can (or should) I change os.path.sep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793573/python-can-or-should-i-change-os-path-sep)

Comment: Thanks  for the links.

Comment: You are welcome, I hope that helps and provides you with some useful answers

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to SSchneid.

using os.path.normpath() solved this.

i.e in above case :

```
path = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'folder_abc','file.abc'))
```