# In Python, how do I specify directory separator in os.path.join() function?

Tags: python, operating-system

I tried the code as below, attempting to change directory separator to forward slash `/` but still stuck in the backslash `\`. The documentation says the function joins paths using directory separator `os.sep`, but this didn't work in my case.

```
import os
os.sep = '/'
print(os.sep)
print(os.path.join('.', 'path'))
```

Comment: Maybe you want `'/'.join(['.', 'path'])` instead?  For most cases (not all, however, so beware) you will get the same output as if your `sep` was set as you had hoped.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Is backslash actually wrong for your operating system?

Answer (score 9):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12086287/3165737) answers the questions why Python uses a particular separator.

That said, you can use the [`Pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) module to construct your paths and specify whether you want a Posix or Windows path.

Example:

```
from pathlib import PurePosixPath, PureWindowsPath

print(PurePosixPath('some', 'silly', 'long', 'path'))
>> some/silly/long/path

print(PureWindowsPath('some', 'silly', 'long', 'path'))
>> some\silly\long\path
```

Make sure you use the `pure` version of `PosixPath` and `WindowsPath`. If you're trying to use `WindowsPath` on a Posix system, you'll get the following error:

```
NotImplementedError: cannot instantiate 'WindowsPath' on your system
```

This is also specified in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib):

> If you want to manipulate Windows paths on a Unix machine (or vice versa). You cannot instantiate a `WindowsPath` when running on Unix, but you can instantiate `PureWindowsPath`.

Answer (score 2):

With [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), you can call [`.as_posix()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.as_posix) on a constructed `Path` to get its string representation with forward slashes as the separator.

Examples:

```py
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path('dirA', 'dirB', 'file.txt').as_posix()
'dirA/dirB/file.txt'
```

```py
>>> from pathlib import PureWindowsPath
>>> PureWindowsPath('dirA\\dirB', 'file.txt').as_posix()
'dirA/dirB/file.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the source code for the different operating systems.  For example, the Mac version is:

```
def join(s, *p):
    path = s 
    for t in p:
        if (not s) or isabs(t):
            path = t 
            continue
        if t[:1] == ':':
            t = t[1:]
        if ':' not in path:
            path = ':' + path
        if path[-1:] != ':':
            path = path + ':' 
        path = path + t 
    return path
```

You can see that it is placed directly into the function.  It does not depend on `os.sep`.  Each Python installation includes the `os.path` functions for every operating system.  They are available in the Python directory under `macpath.py`, `ntpath.py`, and `posixpath.py`.  If you look at each one, you will notice that the `posixpath` module has what you want:

```
import posixpath

print(posixpath.join('.', 'path'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace function in os.path, with self own:

```
import os
path = "public\\INSTALL\\"
print("Initial unmodified join return: '%s'" % os.path.join('.', path) )
native_os_path_join = os.path.join
def modified_join(*args, **kwargs):
    return native_os_path_join(*args, **kwargs).replace('\\', '/')
os.path.join = modified_join
print("Modified join return: '%s'" % os.path.join('.', path) )
```

Output:

```
Initial unmodified join return: '.\public\INSTALL\'
Modified join return: './public/INSTALL/'
```

Answer (score 0):

So to sum up we can simply do the following if for some reason os.path.join() is not working properly

```
   os.sep.join([path,name])
```