# How to correctly read file paths from a directory in python?

Tags: python

I have the following function to read files from a directory.

```
def collect_doc(root, verboose = True):
    filepaths = [os.path.join(root, i) for i in os.listdir(root)]
    if verboose: 
        print(f"filepaths={filepaths}")
    return filepaths
```

It works but I get the following:

```
filepaths=['C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/corpus\\0.txt', 'C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/corpus\\1.txt']
```

I am looking to get the same but as following:

```
 filepaths=['C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/corpus/0.txt', 'C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/corpus/1.txt']
```

Comment: AFAIK, it doesn't really matter, python treats backslashes and forward-slashes the same in Windows paths.

Comment: `os.path.join` will join with your systems `os.sep`. So it seems like you're on a Windows machine but passing in a Linux style path for root.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086224/why-not-os-path-join-use-os-path-sep-or-os-sep

Comment: Both of those will resolve to the same filenames. Windows now (mostly) tolerates forward slashes in filenames even though backslashes are required. As @Chispresso says, the inconsistency you see is probably because `root` had nonstandard forward slashes in it.

Comment: try `r'C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\corpus\0.txt'` and see what you get :)

Comment: If you are looking for a tidy output then ```<str>.replace('\\','/')```